# What means "we might have a room going for you"

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was exchanging texts with an acquainted. We were talking about me moving to his city in December and he said that he is moving in with his friends and that "there might be a room going". He is a native speaker from Australia. What does that mean? Does he want me to move in with them?

Thank you

Comment: It reads like an (conditional) invitation, and *going for you* just means *available for you*.

Comment: It could mean move in, but it also might mean "a place to stay for a few days while you find yourself an apartment."

Comment: It might depend on this person or on the variety of English he speaks, but the way I see it, it could also mean that he's making arrangements for you to get a room _somewhere else_. I think he is the best person to ask for clarification.

Comment: It is probably Australian English. You might want to ask your acquainted what exactly he means. Or wait for an answer here from someone familiar with Australian English (unfortunately, we don't get very many responses from such people).

Answer (score -1):

> we might have a room *going* for you

means there may be a room available for you, "going" as in

> on the *go* = moving, active
>   fair *go* = fair chance
>   *going* off = an active party

Aussie slang [here](http://www.koalanet.com.au/australian-slang.html_).

In contrast to

> the room is *gone*
>   *the room is not available*

Comment: The link of Australian slang that you include does not contain *going*.